# Add a Control to autogenerated ColumnHeader of DataGrid in WPF getting data from SQLite database

Tags: wpf, sqlite, datagrid

I need to create an excel like filter for my data imported from SQLite database.

Importing and showing data from database is doing well with

```
private void UpdateDataGrid(SQLiteConnection con, string sql)
{
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    SQLiteDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sql, con);
    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

    dgMaterials.ItemsSource = dataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;
}
```

AutoGenerateColumns is true so that I get something like this:

[image]

Data are shown in left side datagrid.
In right side listbox I collect the generated column headers with

```
private void dg_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    lb.Items.Add(e.Column.Header.ToString());
}
```

As I said, I want to create excel like filter buttons in header row beside every header text like this

[image]

On XAML site I started like this

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgMaterials"
          IsReadOnly="True"
          CanUserReorderColumns="False"
          CanUserResizeColumns="False"
          CanUserSortColumns="False"
          DockPanel.Dock="Left" AutoGeneratingColumn="dg_AutoGeneratingColumn"
          AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray">

    ... input a button next to every header text ...


</DataGrid>
```

Autocreating of buttons in Headers is working with:

```
private void dg_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    ////string headertext = e.Column.Header.ToString();

    //StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
    //TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
    //tb.Text = e.Column.Header.ToString();
    //sp.Children.Add(tb);

    dgMaterials.AutoGeneratingColumn += (ss, ee) =>
    {
        Button b = new Button() { Content = "...", Name = "btn_" + ee.PropertyName };
        b.Click += HeaderFilterButtonClick;
        StackPanel stackPanel = new StackPanel() { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal };
        stackPanel.Children.Add(new TextBlock() { Text = ee.PropertyName, VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center });
        //stackPanel.Children.Add(new Button() { Content = "...", Name = "btn_" + ee.PropertyName });
        stackPanel.Children.Add(b);
        ee.Column.Header = stackPanel;
    };

    lb.Items.Add(e.Column.Header.ToString());
}
```

thanks @mm8

last problem:

no button is created for the first column header and I don't know why:

[image]

ideas?

Comment: What `HeaderText` are you referring to? There may be several rows but only one column header. So where do you want to get the text in the header from?

Comment: @mm8 I wan't to refer to the auto generated HeaderText. That's my question: Where do I get the header text from? Or rather do I need it? All I need to is to add a button beside every single HeaderText.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the `Header` property of the column to a `Panel` in the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event handler:

```
dgMaterials.AutoGeneratingColumn += (ss, ee) => 
{
    StackPanel stackPanel = new StackPanel() { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal };
    stackPanel.Children.Add(new TextBlock() { Text = ee.PropertyName, VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center });
    stackPanel.Children.Add(new Button() { Content = "..." });
    ee.Column.Header = stackPanel;
};
```

Comment: this is looking good. thanks so far. but I have two more challenges: 1. how can I register the click event for the created buttons? 2. no button is created for the first column header and I don't know why :/

Comment: @Udineska: 1. Like you would register an event handler for any other button: `button.Click += ...`. 2. Do you define any additional columns in the XAML? Please post an image of your first column currently look like.

Comment: @Udineska: Did you try to increase the width of the first column? If you put a breakpoint in `AutoGeneratingColumn`, how many times does it get hit? It should be one for each column.

Comment: I did. Increasing width shows just the same. If I set a breakpoint, it is skipping the first column. Don't know why...

Comment: @Udineska: If you don't hit the breakpoint for the first column, it means that it's not auto-generated, i.e. you are adding it yourself somewhere.

Comment: sorry, stupid mistake. I put your code into the dg_AutoGeneratingColumn method. so the button adding code was assigned after the first auto generated column. now it works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Edit your ColumnHeaderStyle in xaml

```
        <Style x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Themes:DataGridHeaderBorder BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" IsClickable="{TemplateBinding CanUserSort}" IsPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" IsHovered="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SortDirection="{TemplateBinding SortDirection}" SeparatorBrush="{TemplateBinding SeparatorBrush}" SeparatorVisibility="{TemplateBinding SeparatorVisibility}">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                    <Button Content="..." Margin="2" Click="Button_Click"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Themes:DataGridHeaderBorder>
                            <Thumb x:Name="PART_LeftHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderGripperStyle}"/>
                            <Thumb x:Name="PART_RightHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderGripperStyle}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

...
 <DataGrid ColumnHeaderStyle="{DynamicResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyle1}"/>
```

```cs
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //what you want to do on the filter click
}
```

Comment: Got errors: namespaceprefix "Themes" not defined. "DataGridHeaderBorder" not supported in WPF-project.